# Problem Seeding the database after using nwidart package in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, migration, laravel-5.8, laravel-seeding

I am creating a modular application in Laravel and have used a package called [nwidart](https://nwidart.com/laravel-modules/v1/introduction).I am also using Spatie package for Role and Permission based ACL. This works fine, I have created a seeder class inside my module called API using this command

```
php artisan module:make-seed PermissionTableSeeder API
```

This has created a seeder file inside `Modules/API/Database/Seeders directory`. I have further edited the code in the seeder file as shown below:

```
<?php

namespace Modules\API\Database\Seeders;

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Spatie\Permission\Models\Permission;

class PermissionTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {

        $permissions = [
            'role-list',
            'role-create',
            'role-edit',
            'role-delete',
            'blog-list',
            'blog-create',
            'blog-edit',
            'blog-delete'
         ];

        foreach ($permissions as $permission) {
            Permission::create(['name' => $permission]);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is am not aware of the specific command to run the seeder class inside the API module.

Answer (score 1):

To run this seed you'll go through 2 steps:

1- if you didn't change the main module seeder then go to `Modules\API\Database\Seeders\APIDatabaseSeeder` and add the following line to the run function:

`$this->call(PermissionTableSeeder::class);`

Note that you'll need to use the `PermissionTableSeeder` class before running the command.

2- run:
php artisan module:seed API

check the docs for more info https://nwidart.com/laravel-modules/v6/advanced-tools/artisan-commands#moduleseed

Comment: php artisan module:seed is for run all seeds

Answer (score 1):

in my case when module in subfolders and want to run in directly without running other seeder

```
php artisan db:seed --class=WM\Common\Seeder\SmsStatusSeeder
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this command

```
php artisan module:seed <Module Name>
```